# why pandas change (large)numbers when it exports data to csv and excel

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with one column number:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([34032872653290886,57875847776839336],['A','B'],columns=['numbers'])
```

when I save dataframe to excel and to csv, saved data are shown as scientific number and became `34032872653290900, 57875847776839300`.
To convert df I use following codes.

```
df.to_excel('a1.xlsx')
df.to_csv('a1.csv')
```

Is it a bug? Or should I change a setting? I check my code from two system(Mac and windows) and my pandas version is '0.20.2'.

Comment: I did not understand your problem. Do you visualize the numbers in excel, in scientific notation? LIke `34032872653290886` = `3.40e+16`?

Comment: Yes, this is what I see in a cell `3.40329E+16` , This is what really is in excel `34032872653290900`, and this is real value`34032872653290886`.

Comment: This is a problem of number format in Excel. Did you correctly configured the cell number format?

Comment: I think I do that, but I'm not sure. How should I configure that?

Comment: What I believe you have is two concurrent problems: 
1 - You are visualizing numbers on Excel in scientific format
2 - You are saving a integer too big for the internal `int` type of Excel.

Did you try to save the numbers as `float`?

Comment: I just change them to float, but excel round up(down) numbers again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165330/discussion-between-solidsnake-and-mehdi).

Comment: were you able to figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out Excel has a limitation on displaying large numbers, nothing wrong with the CSV writer module.

Got the reply in other post [Python CSV writer truncates long numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42006890/python-csv-writer-truncates-long-numbers)