# Pandas truncating comma-separated list of IDs when converting to csv

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, csv

I am trying to convert a Pandas Dataframe to a CSV, and have some patient IDs stored as numbers I want to convert to comma-separated strings (e.g. [123, 456, 789] becomes "123,456,789"). These lists of patinet IDs represent patients belonging to a cluster generated by a clustering algorithm.

But some of the ID lists I want to store are being truncated in Excel (it's not even all of them, just a few). Unsure why only certain entries are being truncated (they aren't the largest ones, so size of the list isn't an issue). I am aware that Excel truncates large numbers, but I don't think this should be an issue in my case, as I already convert the values to strings before joining them using `",".join`.

Already checked these out, but they haven't been too helpful:
[why pandas change (large)numbers when it exports data to csv and excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48840876/why-pandas-change-largenumbers-when-it-exports-data-to-csv-and-excel)
[Python pandas large floats with to_csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46236711/python-pandas-large-floats-with-to-csv)

Python code to generate IDs

```
patients_in_cluster = tissue_cancer_data["ID"][clustered_data_labels == cluster_label].to_numpy()

clustered_tissue_data.loc[len(clustered_tissue_data)] = "NA"
clustered_tissue_data_size = len(clustered_tissue_data)

patients_in_cluster = helpers.integer_array_to_string(patients_in_cluster)
clustered_tissue_data.iloc[-1, -1] = ",".join(patients_in_cluster)
```

Output of Python code:

```
                                       PatientIDs
1030133,1024647,1030131,1021253,1030129,103013...
1030132,1024645,1020977,1021996,1021906,171711...
1534281,1089967,2068449,1494905,1084226,261977...
2619774,2297298,1172718,1629125,1054774,105477...
1084231,1021893,1717076,1657971,1717085,102448...
```

Output in Excel:

```
1030133,1024647,1030131,1021253,1030129,103013...
######
1534281,1089967,2068449,1494905,1084226,261977...
######
######
```

I want the output in Excel to all be comma-separated lists of IDs. How do I fix this?

Comment: Excel is IMO terrible with CSV's. If you absolutely need to use Excel, then *import* the CSV file and specify that field as text.

Comment: @BigBen To solve this, I decided to use a separator that isn't commas (in my case, I used a semicolon). By solve, I mean solve the problem I posted the question for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I have found appears to be using a separator other than the comma (this can be things like ;, :, and |, in my case I used ;). I don't think this solves the core issue, but will serve as a helpful piece of info to those looking for a solution.